# Logical |+> State Preparation

Tags: error-correction, surface-code, fault-tolerance

From [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1709.02318.pdf) (page 2), they said that

> Surface code qubits can be easily initialized in the logical
> +1-eigenstates Logical |0> and Logical |+> of Logical Z and Logical X by initializing all physical qubits in the corresponding physical
> states Logical |0> and Logical |+>, measuring all stabilizers, and correcting the errors.

Why is it possible to prepare logical |+> by applying Hadamard on all physical qubits and then turn on stabilizers.

The |++> state is not a simulteneous eigenstate of XX and ZZ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\ket}[1]{|#1\rangle}$
Our goal is to produce the logical plus state, $\ket{\bar +}$.

The claim is that it is produced by putting the data qubits in the $\ket{+}^{\otimes n}$ state and doing stabilizer measurements.

Let us see why this works for surface codes. We are going to use a more expansive than usual definition of stabilizer states. Let $S$ be the stabilizer group, with generators $\{S_1,\dots,S_m\}$. Then a stabilizer state $\ket{\psi}$ of $S$ is defined to be one which satisfies the following relationships
$$
S_i\ket{\psi} = s_i\ket{\psi} \quad \text{for } s_i \in \{+1,-1\}.
$$
Instead of demanding that $\ket{\psi}$ is a simultaneous eigenstate of all stablizers with eigenvalue $+1$, we are letting it be the simultaneous eigenstate of stabilizer generators with eigenvalues $(s_1,\dots,s_m)$. For practical computation, this is much more useful.

Next, recall [1] that if we measure the state $\ket{\phi}$ with a Pauli operator $g$, then the post measurement state is one of $\ket{\phi^\pm} = (I \pm g)\ket{\phi}/\sqrt{2}$, with measurement outcome $\pm 1$.

If we measure the state $\ket{+}^{\otimes n}$ with all stabilizers one by one, the final state will be
$$
\ket{\Psi} = \prod_{i=1}^m (I + s_iS_i)\ket{+}^{\otimes n},
$$
with measurement outcomes $s=(s_1,\dots,s_m)$, where $s_i \in \{+1,-1\}$. You can verify that this is a eigenstate of all stabilizers $S_i$.

Why is this the $\ket{\bar +}$ state for the surface code? Recall three properties.

1. The plus state is a +1 eigenstate of $X$, i.e. $X\ket{+} = \ket{+}$.
2. The logical $\bar{X}$ for surface codes is transversal, i.e. consists of a product of physical $X$ gates on some data qubits and $I$ on the rest. Hence $\bar{X}\ket{+}^{\otimes n} = \ket{+}^{\otimes n}$.
3. The plus state is the one with equal amplitude and phase of the zero and plus states, i.e. $\langle 1\ket{+} = \langle 0\ket{+}$.

Also remember that $\ket{\bar 1} = \bar{X}\ket{\bar 0}$. Therefore, we evaluate,
\begin{align}
\langle \bar 1 \ket{\Psi} &= \langle \bar 0| \bar{X} \prod_{i=1}^m (I + s_iS_i)\ket{+}^{\otimes n}, \\
&= \langle \bar 0| \prod_{i=1}^m (I + s_iS_i)\bar{X}\ket{+}^{\otimes n}, \\
&= \langle \bar 0| \prod_{i=1}^m (I + s_iS_i)\ket{+}^{\otimes n}, \\
&= \langle \bar 0 \ket{\Psi}.
\end{align}

Since $\ket{\Psi}$ satisfies property 3 above, it must be the logical plus state.

[1] Nielson and Chuang 10.5.3

Comment: Your explanation is astonished, much appreciated.